# How to go through all the requests in scrapy-splash?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to write a scrapy-splash spider to go to a website, and continuously enter fields into a form, and submit the form. For the loop, for field in field[0:10], it will work for the first field, give me the data I want, and write the files. But for the last 9 elements, I get no response/it never calls the callback function. I tried doing the body of parse in the start_urls function, but got the same response. I hope someone can clear up what I seem to be misunderstanding.

Additional notes: I'm doing this in jupyter, where I predefined my settings and put them in when I initialize my process.
Observations: The first field will work, and then the next 9 will print their respective lua script instantly. I cannot tell if this is because the lua script is not working, or something fundamentally about how scrapy-splash works. Additionally, the print(c) only works once so either the callback is not being called, or the splash_request is not called.

```
c=0
fields = ['']
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'url'
    start_urls = ['url']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with open('script.lua', 'r') as script:
            self.LUA_SOURCE = script.read()
            print(self.LUA_SOURCE)
        
    

    def parse(self, response):
        for field in fields[0:10]:
            try:
                src = self.LUA_SOURCE % (field)
                print(src)
                yield SplashRequest(url=self.start_urls[0],
                                    callback=self.parse2,
                    endpoint='execute',
                    args={'wait': 10,
                          'timeout':60,
                          'lua_source': src},
                    cache_args=['lua_source'],
                )
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        

    def parse2(self, response):
        global c
        c+=1
        print(c)
        try:
            with open(f'text_files/{c}.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(response.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```